# Cannot connect to Azure MySQL database from .NET Connector

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

I tried to connect to the Azure MySQL database using MySQL Workbench and MySQL Shell and it works fine. Now I am trying to connect using following C# code:

```
var connStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "creatur-db.mysql.database.azure.com",
    Database = "test",
    UserID = "creatur_db_main@creatur-db",
    Password = "{my_password}",
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Preferred,
};

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Here I replaced `{my_password}` with password to the database and it gives me an exception inside Open method:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host
>   'creatur-db.mysql.database.azure.com' for user
>   'creatur_db_main@creatur-db' using method 'mysql_native_password'
>   failed with message: The connection string may not be right. Please
>   visit portal for references.

I also tried different connection strings:

```
Server=creatur-db.mysql.database.azure.com; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=creatur_db_main@creatur-db; Pwd={my_password}; SslMode=Preferred
```

and

```
Database=test; Data Source=creatur-db.mysql.database.azure.com; User Id=creatur_db_main@creatur-db; Password={my_password}
```

But none of them worked.

The same exception occurs when I create new connection using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013. It seems the error has something to do with .NET Connector. I tried to use different versions of MySQL.Data.dll, .NET Framework and Visual Studio but no luck.

Comment: I remember having the same problem. It is the .Net connector.

Comment: @FrankBoucher How did you solve it ?

Comment: According to your mentioned `The connection string may not be right.` exception, it seems that the userId format is not correct. But accroding to your code and userId, it is right format. So it is very odd.  I also try your code on my side, it works correctly. I use the  VS 2017, net framework 4.6.1 .and library [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.10.6) .

Comment: @n-necropoliess it was with PowerBi and MySql was on its first day... Now it works. Try to update your references. I wrote you a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a console application using VS2017 I used 
Nuget package MySql.Data and .Net Framework 4.6.1

It works perfectly here What I did.

After Creating the MySQL server I used the CloudShell to connect to the SERVER (not a database).

[image]

Using this code:

```
mysql --host franktest.mysql.database.azure.com --user frank@franktest -p
```

I got an error

```
ERROR 9000 (HY000): Client with IP address '40.76.202.47' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.
```

So I add that IP and at the same time my IP from where I'm connected.

So once the IP were saved. I executed the previous command, and this time it worked perfectly. I created a database named: frankdemo using this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE frankdemo;
```

Then, back in VisualStudio used this code as my Main method, copied from the documentation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "franktest.mysql.database.azure.com",
            Database = "frankdemo",
            UserID = "frank@franktest",
            Password = "gr3enRay14!",
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Required,
        };

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
            conn.Open();

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished dropping table (if existed)");

                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished creating table");

                command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (@name1, @quantity1),
                    (@name2, @quantity2), (@name3, @quantity3);";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", "banana");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity1", 150);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", "orange");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity2", 154);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name3", "apple");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity3", 100);

                int rowCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of rows inserted={0}", rowCount));
            }

            // connection will be closed by the 'using' block
            Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Runed it and it works

[image]

The documentation I'm referring to is:

- [Create an Azure Database for MySQL server by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal)
- [Azure Database for MySQL: Use .NET (C#) to connect and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-csharp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me. The same exception occurs on opening connection.

Comment: @N.Necropoliess can you try to connect to your MySQL Server from the Cloud Shell? like explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal#connect-to-mysql-by-using-the-mysql-command-line-tool

Comment: I successfully connected to the MySQL server from the Cloud Shell but my code still doesn't work. Looks like something is wrong with MySQL.Data.dll that I get from NuGet (version 6.10.6). If I replace it with MySqlConnector then it works fine but unfortunately I cannot use it with NHibernate so I need some way to make MySQL.Data.dll work.

Comment: > If I replace it with MySqlConnector then it works fine but unfortunately I cannot use it with NHibernate

@N.Necropoliess, what are the problem(s) that prevent MySqlConnector working with NHibernate?